# CoreData Aggregate one to many relationships

Tags: swift, core-data, one-to-many

I have a CoreData model with the following "architecture": I have a `Session` entity with `system_version` as an attribute. Then I have a `Views (Session<-->>Views)` entity with a `delta_time` an attribute. Finally I have a `"UI_Elements" (Views <-->> UI_Elements)` entity with a `variable_value` attribute. I would like to filter the content according to a specific `variable_value` value and then display the `delta_time` average grouped by `system_version`.

[image]

I have tried the following implementation:

```
            var expressionDescriptions = [AnyObject]()

            expressionDescriptions.append("views_ui.sessions.systemVersion" as AnyObject)
            let expressionDescription = NSExpressionDescription()
            expressionDescription.name = "Average Time"


            expressionDescription.expression = NSExpression(format: "@avg.views_ui.delta_time_number")
            expressionDescription.expressionResultType = .integer32AttributeType
            expressionDescriptions.append(expressionDescription)



            let fetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "UI_Elements")
            fetch.predicate = requete
            fetch.propertiesToGroupBy = ["views_ui.sessions.systemVersion"]

            fetch.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
            fetch.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "views_ui.sessions.systemVersion", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare(_:)))]
            fetch.propertiesToFetch = expressionDescriptions

            var results:[[String:AnyObject]]?
```

Unfortunately I got the following error:

> CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request:
>    , Invalid keypath (request
>   for aggregate operation on a toOne-only keypath):
>   views_ui.delta_time_number with userInfo of (null)

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to get the desired result by modifying the code as follows:

```
 let keypathExp = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "views_ui.delta_time_number") 
 expressionDescription.expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "average:", arguments: [keypathExp])
```